# what is the maximum storage capacity of adapter in ibm worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

i am trying to get hard coded response from adapter in ibm worklight. As soon as i tried to deploy it. It showed the error..

Adapter deployment failed: Encountered code generation error while compiling function "39": generated bytecode for method exceeds 64K 
limit. (C%3A%5Cworkspace%5CGlobalSalesMobileProject%5Cadapters%5CserviceAdapter/serviceAdapter-impl.js#41)

Can you tell if i want to store data in adapter more than 64k.  how can i achieve this. what is the alternate to the same.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Pooja Midha, Can you provide your adapter JS implementation so we'll have a better understanding at why/how you've reached such a situation? This will help in providing answer.

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, you *should not* store large sets of data in your JavaScript adapter. An Adapter does/should not function as a persistency layer or as a database replacement.

If will you store large volumes of data in the adapter, it is entirely possible that the Worklight Server will eventually run out of memory and start slowing down (will not be able to service a % of your users or at all if things "break down").

The alternative is to use an actual database, or read from file.

It would also be good if you could provide your adapter JS implementation file, so we'll have a better understanding at why/how you've reached such a situation.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a data storage in the adapter issue. This sounds like your JavaScript code itself is too large:

> Encountered code generation error while compiling function "39":
>   generated bytecode for method exceeds 64K limit.

How large is your `.js` file?